# How does EitherT work?

Tags: error-handling, monad-transformers, haskell, either

I spend half of my day trying to figure out how to use EitherT as a way to deal with errors in my code.

I have defined a transformer stack like this.

```
-- Stuff Monad

data StuffConfig = StuffConfig {
  appId     :: T.Text,
  appSecret :: T.Text
}

data StuffState = StuffState {
  stateToken :: Maybe Token,
  stateTime  :: POSIXTime
}

newtype Stuff a = Stuff {
  runStuff :: (ReaderT StuffConfig (StateT StuffState (EitherT T.Text IO))) a
} deriving (Monad, Functor, Applicative, 
            MonadIO, 
            MonadReader StuffConfig,
            MonadState StuffState
            )



askStuff :: StuffConfig -> Stuff a -> IO (Either T.Text a)
askStuff config a = do
  t <- getPOSIXTime 
  runEitherT (evalStateT (runReaderT (runStuff a) config) (StuffState Nothing t))
```

This works quite well as long as i only use the `ReaderT` and `StateT` functions. I am under the impression that now i should be able to write something like this:

```
faultyFunction :: String -> Stuff String
faultyFunction s = do
  when s == "left" $ left "breaking out"
  "right"
```

More important is capturing `Either` return values which should be possible with `hoistEither` from the `errors` package:

```
faultyLookup :: Map -> String -> Stuff String
faultyLookup m k = do
  hoistEither $ lookup k m
```

I read the *real world haskell* chapter on monad transformers and fiddled around with `lift`. But I can't get anything to typecheck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you can't just use the `left` and `hoistEither` functions directly is that unlike `StateT` and `ReaderT` from the [`mtl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) package, the [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either) package doesn't provide a typeclass similar to `MonadReader` or `MonadState`.

The aforementioned typeclasses take care of lifting in the monad stack transparently, but for `EitherT`, you have to do the lifting yourself (or write a `MonadEither` typeclass similar to `MonadReader` et al).

```
faultyFunction :: String -> Stuff String
faultyFunction s = do
  when (s == "left") $ Stuff $ lift $ lift $ left "breaking out"
  return "right"
```

First you need to apply the `Stuff` wrapper, then `lift` over the `ReaderT` transformer and then `lift` again over the `StateT` transformer.

You probably want to write utility functions for yourself such as

```
stuffLeft :: T.Text -> Stuff a
stuffLeft = Stuff . lift . lift . left
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
faultyFunction :: String -> Stuff String
faultyFunction s = do
  when (s == "left") $ stuffLeft "breaking out"
  return "right"
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Control.Monad.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html) from `mtl`, if you define an `Error` instance for `Text`.

```
instance Error T.Text where
  strMsg = T.pack
```

Now you can change the definition of `Stuff` implement `left` and `hoistEither` like this:

```
newtype Stuff a = Stuff {
  runStuff :: (ReaderT StuffConfig (StateT StuffState (ErrorT T.Text IO))) a
} deriving (Monad, Functor, Applicative,
            MonadIO,
            MonadReader StuffConfig,
            MonadState StuffState,
            MonadError T.Text
            )

left :: T.Text -> Stuff a
left = throwError

hoistEither :: Either T.Text a -> Stuff a
hoistEither = Stuff . lift . lift . ErrorT . return
```

With this your original `faultyFunction` type-checks without any manual lifting.

You can also write generic implementations for `left` and `hoistEither` which work for any instance of `MonadError` (using `either` from `Data.Either`):

```
left :: MonadError e m => e -> m a
left = throwError

hoistEither :: MonadError e m => Either e a -> m a
hoistEither = either throwError return
```

Comment: Yay thanks! ... i tried `lift . lift . lift` and wondered why it didn't worked. I wanted to use `EitherT` cause the author of the `errors` package seems to be reluctant to use `ErrorT`.

Comment: @Florian Author of the `errors` package here.  I discussed the reason I don't use `ErrorT` [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/errors-10-simplified-error-handling.html).  However, the reason for no `MonadError` instance is because I am working on a more principled alternative that allows `catch` to change the error value's type.  I know that sounds trivial, but I err on the side of caution, especially when I know that a better solution exists, since it easier to add features than remove them.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez sounds reasonable ... but until then it's inconvenient :(

Comment: @Florian Yeah, I know.  Also, it's technically out of my hands anyway since I don't even maintain the `either` package in the first place.  You can always define your own `MonadError` instance for your own projects as a last resort.  It's not really hard.  Just copy the `MonadError` instance for `ErrorT` from the `mtl` package.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to shang's answer: `MonadError` is basically the corresponding type class to `EitherT`. You can add its instance for `EitherT` (for some reason it's commented out in the `either` library):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
  hiding (left, right, hoistEither)

instance Monad m => MonadError e (EitherT e m) where
  throwError = EitherT . return . Left
  EitherT m `catchError` h = EitherT $ m >>= \a -> case a of
    Left  l -> runEitherT (h l)
    Right r -> return (Right r)
```

Then, define your own methods that are generalized to `MonadError`:

```
left :: MonadError e m => e -> m a
left = throwError
{-# INLINE left #-}

right :: MonadError e m => a -> m a
right = return
{-# INLINE right #-}

hoistEither :: MonadError e m => Either e a -> m a
hoistEither (Left a)  = throwError a
hoistEither (Right e) = return e
{-# INLINE hoistEither #-}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

newtype Stuff a = Stuff {
  runStuff :: (ReaderT Int (StateT Char (EitherT T.Text IO))) a
} deriving (Monad, Functor,
            MonadReader Int,
            MonadError T.Text, -- <--- MonadError instance
            MonadState Char
            )


faultyLookup :: (Ord k) => Map.Map k a -> k -> Stuff a
faultyLookup m k =
  maybe (left $ T.pack "Lookup error") right $ Map.lookup k m
```

or generalize it to

```
faultyLookup :: (MonadError T.Text m, Ord k) => Map.Map k a -> k -> m a
faultyLookup m k =
  maybe (left $ T.pack "Lookup error") right $ Map.lookup k m
```

Comment: or use `ErrorT` and add a `OtherError` constructor for your `Error` instance. Then you can say `strMsg = OtherError`. It's not pretty and it's absolutely useless, but so is having to include this stuff in your codebase, basically reinventing the wheel because the author of `EitherT` felt like it's not his job. I've tried switching from ErrorT to EitherT and I just went back realizing that I've wasted a lot of time. What's the point of a monad transformer that you can't stack properly?